# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in C:\xampp\htdocs\policycode\sample_code\policy1.php on line 17

Tags: php

Below is the program  i have created using PHP.

```
$LogManger->getLogManger()->reset();
    $configPath = policy1->getResource("/open-pep.properties")->toURI()->getPath();
    $pepAgentFactory= new StdPepAgentFactory($configPath);
    $pepAgent =$pepAgentFactory->getPepAgent();
```

The program can't find open-pep.properties file. How to find that properties file and solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

`policy1` is presumably a variable, so you need to prefix it with a `$` sign:

```
$configPath = $policy1->getResource("/open-pep.properties")->toURI()->getPath();
# Here -------^
```